# Change date in XML file from perl

Tags: perl, sed

I have a large file in which i have to update the date of next 5 day whenever my perl script run . I am using sed command to update the  date into the file but it is not working i am getting error :

XML File format  :

```
<StayDateRange Start="2011-03-28"/>
```

I am getting below error when executing the command from perl script but the same command is working from terminal :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 51: Unterminated `s' command
```

Command :

```
my $change_date = `sed -ie 's/Start="\(.*\)"/Start="'"$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + 9 day")"'"/g' $file`;
```

I tried using quotemeta as well but i think there is some other issue in this

Answer (score 4):

Changing XML with regular expressions is fundamentally flawed. XML is contextual, but regular expressions are not.

The solution is therefore: Use a parser.

`XML::Twig` is pretty easy, and it supports `xpath` - which is quite a bit like a regular expression language, that works in a contextual fashion appropriate to XML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# the parser
use XML::Twig;
#time handling
use Time::Piece;
#ONE_DAY macro. 
use Time::Seconds;


my $filename = 'file_to_modify.xml'; 

#open and parse the file into memory. 
open ( my $input, '<', $filename ) or die $!;    
my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( $input ); 
close ( $input );

#locate all nodes called '<StayDateRange>' 
#Note - could use '//StayDateRange[@Start]' to limit it to just the
#ones with an attribute we're looking for. 
foreach my $staydaterange ( $xml -> get_xpath('//StayDateRange') ) {
    my $target_date = localtime;
    #add 5 days to today. 
    $target_date += 5 * ONE_DAY; 
    #update the attribute of the XML element.
    $staydaterange->set_att('Start', $target_date -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d"));
}
#set output format
$xml -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
#output to screen for testing
$xml -> print;

#rewrite the file. 
open ( my $output, '>', $filename ) or warn $!;
$xml -> print ( $output );
close ( $output );
```

But to answer your underlying question - your problem is quoting. You have backticks, then single quotes, with single quotes inside them. Having execute quotes (`$()`) within backticks, with quotes around them is just asking for the trouble you're having.

But you don't actually need to use `sed` within perl at all, because even if you just want to regex transform - `perl` can do that.

Comment: I don't have XML::Twig module installed and i cannot add this module

Comment: @Developer What about XML::LibXML?

Comment: @XML::LibXML i have

Comment: I am trying to use perl one liner as well perl -pe 'my $new_date = "2016-12-12"; s/<Start=(.*)>/<Start=$new_date>/g' Abc.xml but this not changing the value

Comment: @Developer As Sobrique mentioned, modifying XML with regular expressions is a terrible idea. You'll need more than 1 line of code for this.

Comment: This above also works in `XML::LibXML`. It's not much different.

Answer (score 0):

This command modifies your file `f.xml` and backs up the original to `f.xml.bk`

```
D9=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d9days` perl -i.bk -pe 's/(Start=)".*?"/$1"$ENV{D9}"/g' f.xml
```

Use `-i` instead of `-i.bk` to drop the backup part.

Not sure if you wanted to use nine days after the existing dates or after today.

While in general I agree with @Matt Jacob that XML should be parsed, in real life ad hoc situations when the clock is working against you and you can trust that nobody (your future self included) wont be adding `Start` attributes to other tags that might not even be dates, and nobody will begin writing `Start = "..."` or `Start        = '...'` with spaces and `'`, then I think simple regexp'es are ok. Depends on situation. XML-parsing should be in your "tool box" though.